# Fixing the geometry of the inset faces after "shade smooth" and applying modifiers

Tags: modifiers, faces, subdivision-surface, bevel, smooth

I'm trying to fix the geometry of the inset faces on the pillar after I used the "shade smooth" option. I added the Subdivision surface Modifier and the Bevel Modifier, but still the faces which are inset into the pillar, look bad. The inset faces should be with sharp corners all the way, meanwhile I get this. I also tried the Auto Smooth option instead of Bevel Modifier but no change there either. All transforms (incl. scale) after creation are applied. I'll be grateful for help.

[image: weird geometry]

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: This looks like shading artifacts because the face is not coplanar. What does the top of the object look like ?

Comment: @Gorgious It looks the same as the bottom.

https://imgur.com/a/ddwIVub

Comment: @moonboots there it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/c4c30b7c6a6a408f9194013a4f91ff16

Comment: Oh I think you have a subdivision surface and / or your scale is not correctly applied

Comment: @Gorgious The scale is correctly applied - I've applied it indeed with Ctrl+A. Subdivision Surface Modifier is on, as I mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your topology. You have given a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object (which may be not necessary by the way) but with the current topology it rounds these slots. To keep them square create this edge loop with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through). You also need to get rid of overlapping vertices with a *Merge* operation.

[image]

Comment: Disabling Subdivision Surface seems to solve the problem, yet I'd like this object to be more subdivided. I do not get the second part of the answer. "A" key doesn't corelate with orthogonal cutting in my version (2.92), it does nothing, it's not assigned to the Knife tool.

Comment: oh ok until Blender 3 you need to use K to activate, Z to cut through, C to cut orthogonally

Comment: You can disable Subdivision Surface because it seems useless here, but the reason why you had these effects is because of your bad topology, so if you want to keep the Subdivision Surface for some reason, add this edge loop to keep these slots rectangular